# Magento2.3: Reward points vs Loyalty Points

Tags: magento2.3, reward

In Magento 2, we can see the terms called Reward Points and Loyalty points. Is those the things are same or each are having separate functionalities.

Your guidance needed!

Answer (score 1):

Please Refer this link you will see the difference 
https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/marketing/rewards-loyalty.html